# Activity with constructor

Tags: android

I have a problem to start My Activity with constructor
I want to pass an array of objects without using the preference the only solution is to use a constructor

```
public class ApresConnextionActivity extends Activity {

    public Bts[] listeBts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.apresconnect);
        final Button btsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btbts);
        //boutonbts
        btsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

                Log.w("myApp",""+listeBts.length);
                BtsBoutonActivity btba = new BtsBoutonActivity(listeBts);                   
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), btba.getClass());
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
         new JSONParseBts().execute();
    }
    public class JSONParseBts extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> { ... }

}



public class BtsBoutonActivity extends Activity {
    Bts[] listeBts;
    cellule[] listecellule;
    int i,xx=0;

    public BtsBoutonActivity(Bts[] listeBts2) {
        this.listeBts=listeBts2;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.btsbouton);
        //Log.w("myApp",""+listeBts.length);
     final Button[] b = new Button[listeBts.length];
         LinearLayout ll3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2); // Btn  

            for(i = 0; i < listeBts.length; i++){
                //Log.w("myApp",listeBts[i].toString());
        b[i] = new Button(BtsBoutonActivity.this);
        b[i].setText(listeBts[i].getNombts());
         xx =listeBts[i].getIdbts();
        Log.w("myApp",""+xx);
        b[i].setId(xx);
        ll3.addView(b[i]);

        final Button btbts = (Button) findViewById(xx);
        btbts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast saved_message=Toast.makeText(BtsBoutonActivity.this,btbts.getText()+"  "+btbts.getId(),1);
          saved_message.show();                        


          }});

            }
    }


}

05-09 20:14:31.121: E/AndroidRuntime(596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pfe.essat.com/pfe.essat.com.BtsBoutonActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class pfe.essat.com.BtsBoutonActivity; no empty constructor
```

this is a problem of the declaration in the file manifest maybe !!! 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manually instantiate activities in Android so don't use constructors to pass the data between Activities.

Refer to [this thread](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html) on how to properly pass a list of object between activities.

Comment: thx a lot
I tried but how do you pass a specific list(not String,int ..etc)  
I did like that ** i.putExtra("tabbts", listeBts); ** 
and  I called ** Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();** **listeBts = (Bts[]) b.get("lisbts");**  the erreur  is 'unable to marshal value Bts'

Comment: You need that class to implement parcelable / serializable. See the link I provided you. Alternately you can make a custom class with a public static array and before you start the activity, set it's array and read it on the other end. Also you can pass data with your application class, sql too

Comment: it is what I did (serializable) My array is already built price starting from sql query I want to minimize communication with the database that's why
now when I want to use the array erreur is 
** java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pfe.essat.com/pfe.essat.com.BtsBoutonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException **
the array is empty :/

Comment: I found the solution but another problem opposes 
**
05-10 16:29:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pfe.essat.com/pfe.essat.com.BtsBoutonActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to pfe.essat.objet.com.Bts[]
**

Comment: please open a new question a give me the link. tough I am pretty busy with my masters degree (sorry about that)

Comment: thank you very much not matter when you have time this is new subject thx a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154807/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-pfe-essat-obj

Comment: I have answered your second post, please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass data from one activity to another using the constructor. You need to use intents.

```
intent = new Intent(this, Timer.class);
//add the data you want to pass to the other activity here...
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", data);
startActivity(intent); //or use startActivityForResult to check if activity really exists
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html You can find more information on this link. It's explained in a very clearly and easy to understanding way.

Comment: I found the solution but another problem opposes ** 05-10 16:29:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pfe.essat.com/pfe.essat.com.BtsBoutonActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to pfe.essat.objet.com.Bts[] **

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information please, where do you get that error ? (maybe you can take a screenshot)

Comment: this is new subject thx a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154807/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-pfe-essat-obj